# Should constexpr imply inline for specializations?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, constexpr

In MSVC2019 16.10 I've started to get "already defined" errors when including a header with specializations of static constexpr class functions. Minimal reproduction case:

```
#pragma once

template <typename T>
struct foo
{
    static constexpr void bar() {}
};

template <>
constexpr void foo<int>::bar() {}
```

Including this header in two source files gives:

```
Source2.obj : error LNK2005: "public: static void __cdecl foo<int>::bar(void)" (?bar@?$foo@H@@SAXXZ) already defined in Source1.obj
```

As far as I can see, constexpr should imply inline in this case. Adding inline or changing to consteval works. Making a specialization on a global template function links as well. It works on earlier version of Visual Studio, and clang has no issues either. Is this a compiler bug?

Answer (score 0):

> *Is this a compiler bug?*

Well, Microsoft's [own documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/constexpr-cpp?view=msvc-160) would suggest that yes, it is:

> #### constexpr functions
>
> ... 
> A **`constexpr`** function or constructor is implicitly **`inline`**.